# Uninstall Application using a later version of msi

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

We have a custom WIX bootstrapper installer. Bootstrapper bundle chains 3 individual application msi. Bootstrapper custom UI allows user to choose which application to install and based on the selection custom bootstrapper will install its msi.

Now consider the scenario.
Application, say A1 version 1.0.0.50 is installed in the system. Assume bootstrapper version is also 1.0.0.50

Assume next version of bootstrapper installer with some updates is available, Assume its version is 1.0.0.51.
Using this one I want to install second application , say A2.
Also I want to uninstall A1.  Currently we support upgrading A1 to 1.0.0.51 version using this latest installer.

But I want to check the possibility of uninstalling A1 using the latest  bootstrapper version. How do I implement it?
Because as per our project requirements, end user should be able to uninstall A1 using any version of bootstrapper.

I have seen in registry it stores the Uninstallstring for each msi. If I run uninstallstring value , for e.g MsiExec.exe /X{90140000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}
Will it exactly does what is done by msi uninstall ? will it handle cleaning registry entry entries, deleting installed files etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't go to registries for this. MSI database has an upgrade table which will hopefully fulfill your requirement(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372379(v=vs.85).aspx). Add an entry with Upgrade Code of installed MSI, provide version boundaries under VersionMin & VersionMax, set the attribute 769 or something else depending on your requirement, create a new public property and add it to SecureCustomProperties. 
Lastly during installation enable windows logging and check the logs for standard actions like findrelatedproducts and removeexistingproducts if you face any issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please detail out it with an example.E.g I did not understand well about setting attributes and Secure cutomproperties.

Comment: Current upgrade table in my msis are as follows <Upgrade Id='$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)' >
      <UpgradeVersion Minimum='1.0.0.0'
                      Maximum='99.0.0.0'
                      Property='PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED'
                      IncludeMinimum='yes'
                      IncludeMaximum='no'
                      OnlyDetect='no'
                       />
      
    </Upgrade>

Comment: Is this correct? Upgrade to a higher version is working fine.
 During upgrade it uninstalls old version and install new version.
 But instead of Upgrade If I just want to uninstall it is not doing that

Comment: Welcome and I apologize if I took your scenario the other way around. If you requirement is only to uninstall and not a major upgrade, go ahead by creating a custom action that triggers the uninstall of the application you want to uninstall. You can find vbscript for such custom actions at {http://www.symantec.com/connect/downloads/uninstall-msi-vbscript}